# I am unable to deploy my nextjs application on azure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, next.js

I have been trying to deploy my next.js application on azure devops project service.

I have set up CI and CD of my project which is linked with the azure repos.
Even if my pipeline succeeds I get "INTERNAL SERVER ERROR" or " Application error",even though the application runs fine on my local.

I have tried a node applicaton , which runs with the same pipleline tasks.

I have tried adding a web.config file and still no luck with it.

Can anyone suggest me what I could me missing?

Adding a web.config file
Disabling a web.config option in release pipeline
Adding new tasks in the pipelines such as npm run build

My web.config file is as follows:

```
    <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
    <rule name="StaticContent">
      <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
    </rule>

    <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
    <rule name="DynamicContent">
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>

<!-- 'bin' directory has no special meaning in node.js and apps can be placed in it -->
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <hiddenSegments>
      <remove segment="bin"/>
    </hiddenSegments>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>

<!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />

<!--
  You can control how Node is hosted within IIS using the following options:
    * watchedFiles: semi-colon separated list of files that will be watched for changes to restart the server
    * node_env: will be propagated to node as NODE_ENV environment variable
    * debuggingEnabled - controls whether the built-in debugger is enabled
  See https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config for a full list of options
-->
<!--<iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"/>-->
```

My application end point gives application error result, even though I think I have completed almost whole procedure.

Comment: I don't think it's a problem with deployment, your application is not working on the environment, may be a configuration issue or something else. You may look into the log for the azure web app to see the actual exception.

Comment: May be the issue is wrt port. Please check

Comment: @Sahit The port I am using for my application is 3000. That's right I guess

Comment: if you are deploying to Azure app service , you can check the following thread https://spectrum.chat/next-js/general/deploying-nextjs-to-azure~d0678f3a-29d4-4c56-8853-048ce938fa4d There is a you tube video which might be helpful  https://youtu.be/Ut8KYyCOqpA

Comment: here you can find details related to troubleshooting steps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/troubleshooting?view=azure-devops

Comment: Can you share your release definition and detailed web.config?